# Cannot insert duplicate key when directly assigning Foreign Key with EF

Tags: entity-framework

Model:

```
class TableA
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID {get;set;}
}

class TableB
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public int TableAID {get;set;}
    [ForeignKey("TableAID")]
    public virtual TableA TableA {get;set;}
}
```

Code:

```
var copyB = sourceDb.TableB.Single(B => B.ID == TableBID_Param); //EG. B.ID == 17
copyB.TableAID = TableAID_Param; //EG. B.TableAID = 5;
destDb.TableB.Add(copyB);
destDb.SaveChanges(); //Error occurs here
```

I have changed the Foreign Key ID, and the Primary Key should be regenerated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here, is the the copyB object is:

- still associated with sourceDb
- likely lazy loading TableA (if TableAID has a value)

The TableA navigation property will take precedence over the TableAID foreign key property. DestDb will try to insert the TableA object, and this likely already exists (possibly from a previous successful execution of this flawed code).

You should quarantine your objects between contexts, in a similar way that you should use a separate ViewModel when sending data to a web client - you have control how it gets serialised. This also makes it clear to a future developer that a new Primary Key is expected (not implied)

Extend TableB:

```
class TableB
{
    public string SomeData {get;set;} //Let's pretend there's something interesting to clone

    public TableA ContextClone()
    {
        var clone = new TableA();
        clone.SomeData = SomeData;
        //Nothing else get's assigned - it's up to the caller to map ForeignKeys
    }
}
```

New Code:

```
var sourceB= sourceDb.TableB.Single(B => B.ID == TableBID_Param); //EG. B.ID == 17
var clone = sourceB.ContextClone();
clone.TableAID = TableAID_Param; //EG. B.TableAID = 5;
destDb.TableB.Add(clone);
destDb.SaveChanges();
```